# Decorators, Webpack, and ProvidePlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-next

I use decorators and webpack (3 if that matters). Is there a way to configure the ProvidePlugin so that I can just use `@decorator` without having import it?

I've tried:

```
plugins: [new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  'decorator': 'decorator-lib'
})]

plugins: [new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  '@decorator': 'decorator-lib'
})]
```

I suppose as an alternative I could import it into its own chunk file and then attach that script globally, but that smells more hacky, though I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: are you using babel ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I'm currently using decorators, I'd just like the convenience of not having to import them all the time.

Comment: is 'decorator-lib' in node_modules ? or is it your module ?*

Comment: yes, 'decorator-lib' is just a placeholder for whatever decorator library

Comment: Have you tried using [babel-plugin-transform-decorators](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-decorators/)?

Comment: @Mrchief babel-plugin-transform-decorators is for Babel 7.x+, I'm using 6.26.0, and while I could certainly look into upgrading Babel to use that package, I have my doubts that it actually addresses the question (how to use Webpack's `ProvidePlugin` to avoid having to import a specific decorator library each time). Again, this isn't about using decorators. They work just fine. I simply don't want to have to include an import statement to use the decorator.

Comment: @BrandonTom that's not correct. That plugin has been around for a long time. But I see that it has been renamed to babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy (for Babel 6.x) recently.